What's the point of the left Fcrit value in a 2-tailed F-test?
In a 2-tailed F-test, there are 2 critical values right? One on the right and one on the left.
You can get the one on the right by using an F-table and the one on the left by getting the reciprocal of some other F-crit value.
My issue though is that since most Fcrit values are bigger than one, wouldn't the reciprocal of most of them be less than one?
And since an F-statistic has the bigger variance at the top, wouldn't that mean that there's almost no chance that it would be less than the Fcrit value on the left?
So my question is what's the point of the left Fcrit value or the lower rejection region if there's pretty much no chance that the F-statistic will fall there?
The only way I can see the left Fcrit value making sense is if we use the reciprocal of the F-statistic to check if it will fall in the lower rejection region. Much like how it's done in Left-tailed F test.
But all of the videos I've watched about 2 tailed F-test stopped once they proved that it doesn't fall in the upper rejection region. I really feel like I'm missing a step here.

You appear to be conflating two distinct approaches. If you put the bigger variance on top, you're dealing with a different situation to one where you look in the left $\alpha/2$ of the F distribution.

Some of the trouble with how the F-test is taught is that it is explicitly a test of variance equality, much as a t-test compares the means of two groups. However, the F-test can be cleverly used to compare means by comparing particular variances (“within” and “between” are typical names for these variances), which is where we get “variance” in the “analysis of variance” comparison of group means. This distinction is not necessarily made clear in discussions of the F-test (of which I might be guilty right now).
